# Spring @Transaction rollbackfor and Custom Repository

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-data

I have one transaction not rolling back and I can't figure why, I'm using it with a custom repository so not sure if that's the problem, could it be that EntityManager is running in a different transaction scope?

Here's my service:

```
@Service
public class SchedulingProgramService {
    @Autowired
    SchedulingProgramRepository schedulingprogramRepository;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public SchedulingProgram activateSchedulingProgram(String id) throws Exception {
        SchedulingProgram schedulingprogram = schedulingprogramRepository.findOne(id);

        if (schedulingprogram != null) {
            schedulingprogramRepository.deactivateAllSchedulingPrograms();

            if (true) //Just to test if rollback works
                throw new Exception("");

            schedulingprogram.accepted = true;
            schedulingprogramRepository.save(schedulingprogram);
            return schedulingprogram;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
    }
}
```

My Custom Repository Interface:

```
public interface SchedulingProgramRepositoryCustom {
    void deactivateAllSchedulingPrograms();
}
```

And Implementation:

```
public class SchedulingProgramRepositoryImpl implements SchedulingProgramRepositoryCustom {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deactivateAllSchedulingPrograms()
    {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("update SchedulingProgram sp set accepted = :accepted WHERE accepted = :accepted2");
        query.setParameter("accepted", false);
        query.setParameter("accepted2", true);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

And finally the actual Repository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface SchedulingProgramRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<SchedulingProgram, String>, SchedulingProgramRepositoryCustom {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    void deactivateAllSchedulingPrograms();
}
```

I'm throwing an Exception directly in the Service just for testing, as you can see I have rollbackFor set to Exception.class so I'd assume the changes done in the deactivateAllSchedulingPrograms would be rolled back, but they aren't.
Is the EntityManager in my custom repository causing issues?

I'm also not sure what deactivateAllSchedulingPrograms methods I should annotate as @Transactional, is it enough to annotate the one in SchedulingProgramRepository or do I also need to annotate the one in SchedulingProgramRepositoryImpl? I tried both ways and doesn't make a difference. Actually I think even without annotating them this should work since my Service method is annotated with @Transactional, but I'm obviously doing something wrong here.

**Update**

Vihar, yes I do:

```
<!-- Set session factory -->
    <bean id="baseEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="baseDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="myproject.model" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${base.db.dialect}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Set transaction manager -->
    <bean id="baseTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="baseEntityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Am I missing something?

problemMaker101, I'm aware that I could only use them in the Service, but I think it's a good policy to also have them in the repositories. What if I also access those methods without using a proxy? It's safer having them on both and as Spring docs also state there's no issue with that. My only doubt is if I need to add the @Transaction to both SchedulingProgramRepository and SchedulingProgramRepositoryImpl or to only one of them.

Comment: in your spring configuration file have you defined a `transactionManager` bean? simply marking a method as transactional doesnt work

Comment: It's not a good practice to put \@Transactional in the repository class, also quot from the Spring doc:'When using proxies, you should apply the \@Transactional annotation only to methods with public visibility'. Set the \@Transactional in service classes is enough.

Comment: I was trying to reply to your comments, but seems I can only use a small amount of characters. So will need to post it as an answer...

Comment: @mfc: You can amend your question with further information by using the "edit" link. I have done that for you, this time.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @Transactional from interface and make the service impl classes as @Transactional(rollbackFor="Throwable.class").